# Webpack config externals how to mix array and object syntax

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-5

Currently I have a webpack config with the externals set like so:

```
externals: [nodeExternals(), "inferno-helmet"]
```

I'm trying to add the [sharp image processing library to my project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp). [According to the docs](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#webpack), in order to work with a project that uses webpack, externals must be set like so:

```
externals: {
  'sharp': 'commonjs sharp'
}
```

I figure for sharp and inferno-helmet, the externals would look like this:

```
externals: {
    'sharp': 'commonjs sharp',
    'inferno-helmet': 'inferno-helmet',
    // ?
}
```

I don't understand how to properly use node externals with this syntax. The [README for the webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) only shows examples of passing an array to externals. How can I include all three of the node externals, inferno-helmet, and sharp in the externals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is a valid answer:

```js
externals: [nodeExternals(), "inferno-helmet", {sharp: 'commonjs sharp'}]
```